# Unity3D - 2D object rotation based on touch moved (diff between touches)

Tags: vector, rotation, unity-game-engine

I´m newbie in Unity. I want rotate my 2D object based on user touch moved (moved finger on the screen). I have this code:

```
void Update ()
{
    if (Input.touches.Length > 0) {
         t = Input.GetTouch (0);

        if (t.phase == TouchPhase.Moved) {
            Vector3 movePos = new Vector3 (t.position.x, t.position.y, 0);
            var objectPos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint (transform.position);
            var dir = movePos - objectPos; 
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler (new Vector3 (0f, 0f, Mathf.Atan2 (dir.y, dir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg));
        }
    }
}
```

This code rotate the object based on user touch but when I touch screen again in another position and do touch move, it will rotate the whole object to the actual touch and then it will do correct object rotation based on touch move.

And I dont´t want rotate the whole object based on touch position but rotate the object only based on touch move. Do you understand me? Can you help me? How should I rewrite my code?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you, try to use this code below:

```
private float turnSpeed = 5f;
private Vector2 movement;

void Update()
{
    Vector2 currentPosition = transform.position;

    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);

        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
        {
            Vector2 moveTowards = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(touch.position);

            movement = moveTowards - currentPosition;
            movement.Normalize();
        }
    }

    float targetAngle = Mathf.Atan2(movement.y, movement.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, targetAngle), turnSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Let me know if is what you want. Also, there is a complete sample here: https://github.com/joaokucera/unity-2d-object-rotation

Comment: It´s not exactly what I want. When I touch the screen, it will rotate the object to the touch, but I don´t what rotate object to the point of the touch. I want rotate object only as is different between touch moved (maybe delta between touches?)...Do you understand?

Answer (score 0):

Look into using [deltaPosition](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Touch-deltaPosition.html) instead of position on your touch. That should get you in the right direction.

```
var movedVector = t.deltaPosition;
```

Edit:

Here is a possible integration with your existing code. I don't have Unity on this PC so this is entirely untested. The main idea is you are getting a change in the finger position between frames. You then scale that change by move speed, and of course, the change in time between frame renders (delta time).

How the object rotates relative to that information is up to you. I just inserted the logic into your existing code.

```
float moveSpeed = 2.0f;

void Update ()
{
    if (Input.touches.Length > 0) {
         t = Input.GetTouch (0);

        if (t.phase == TouchPhase.Moved) {
            var delta = t.deltaPosition * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler (new Vector3 (0f, 0f, Mathf.Atan2 (delta .y, delta.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how I should it use? What I should do? Thx a lot!